# combined aggregation functions for more efficient plotting

Tags: influxdb, grafana

My computing cluster monitoring data is stored in an influx DB with the following shape (minus a few columns):

```
time                           number parti user
----                           ------ ----- ----
2017-06-02T06:58:52.854866584Z 59     gr01  user01
2017-06-02T06:58:52.854866584Z 6      gr01  user02
2017-06-02T06:58:52.854866584Z 295    gr02  user03
2017-06-02T06:58:52.854866584Z 904    gr03  user04
```

data points are every 10 minutes. Right now I am plotting the sum for each "parti" with:

```
select sum(number) from status_logs where time > now() - 1h group by time(10m), parti
```

However, this becomes very slow when I show more than a few days due to the time(10m). I cannot use a varying time window because the sum() would not make sense anymore.

My question : would there be a way to take the **average of the sum** over a (variable) time window ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think what you are looking for is continuous queries. Are you aware of it?
 https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/continuous_queries/

Comment: Hi, I was not aware of this, indeed. However, this is less flexible than combined aggregation.

Comment: I agree, but AFAIK at this point, this is the best Influx can do.